# Task "not yet computed": An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework, asynchronous, .net-4.5

Been working with optimizing a clients search function so that he can execute several search at once without it effecting the load time (atleast not to much).
The search works in a way that we first get a json for an external service, converts this into a datacontract and then saves it in our database and returns entity objects.

Before, I had all this in one method and successfully loaded several searches asynchronously but then I though that if i could separate the service calls that gets the json from the part that saves it into our own database and returns the objects then it should be able to go alot faster since the search service is actually the real search.

So now i have two OperationContracts:

```
    [OperationContract]
    SwepubHeader DoSwepubSearchAdvanced(string searchQuery, string hiddenSearchWord, Dictionary<string, string> advancedSearchParameters);

    [OperationContract]
    List<List<SearchItem>> GetSearchResults(List<SwepubHeader> headers);
```

The first goes to a search service called swepub and retieves the json call and parses it to a DataContract
The second saves the data to the database and returns the data as EntityFramework objects. The user is able to sent several SwepubHeader-DataContract and then get several search results

In the web site where I want to make the asynchronous calls my code looks like this:

```
    List<Task<SwepubHeader>> _taskList = new List<Task<SwepubHeader>>();

    public SwepubHeader[] DoSearchAdvanced(SwepubSearchServiceClient client, string query,
        string[] subQuerys, Dictionary<string, string> advancedSearchParameters)
    {
        _taskList = new List<Task<SwepubHeader>>();
        DoSearchAdvancedAsync(client, query, subQuerys, advancedSearchParameters);

        return _taskList.Select(task => task.Result).ToArray();
    }
    private async void DoSearchAdvancedAsync(SwepubSearchServiceClient client, string query, IEnumerable<string> subQuerys, Dictionary<string, string> advancedSearchParameters)
    {
        foreach (string subQuery in subQuerys)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(subQuery))
            {
                // Starts an async search
                _taskList.Add(client.DoSwepubSearchAdvancedAsync(query, subQuery,
                    advancedSearchParameters));
            }
        }
        // Awaits all async searches to finish
        await Task.WhenAll(_taskList);
    }
```

The code fails at:

```
return _taskList.Select(task => task.Result).ToArray();
```

What am I missing? All task.Result will show "not yet computed". Could it have something to do with that I do HttpWebRequests in DoSwepubSearchAdvanced?

Answer (score 4):

The problem you're seeing is due to your use of `async void`. As a general rule, you should avoid `async void`; [see my MSDN article for more information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

There's another problem in your design: [it's not a good idea to wrap asynchronous methods within synchronous methods](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx). Once you work around the `async void` problems, you'll still end up with [deadlock issues that I describe on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

The proper solution is to replace `DoSearchAdvanced` with an asynchronous method:

```
public Task<SwepubHeader[]> DoSearchAdvancedAsync(
    SwepubSearchServiceClient client,
    string query, string[] subQuerys,
    Dictionary<string, string> advancedSearchParameters)
{
  return Task.WhenAll(subQuerys
      .Where(subQuery => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(subQuery))
      .Select(subQuery => client.DoSwepubSearchAdvancedAsync(
          query, subQuery, advancedSearchParameters)));
}
```

And then modify your web site call to `await` the result.